# Failed to build gem native extension while installing rmovie gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ffmpeg

I am trying to install **rmovie gem** on Ubuntu Desktop 12.04 LTS. `ffmpeg` is installed but I'm getting this error:

```
$ gem install rmovie
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rmovie:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /home/ror_dev/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p362/bin/ruby extconf.rb
gcc -c -fpic -g  qp_movie.c -o qp_movie.o
In file included from qp_movie.c:4:0:
qp_util.h:4:28: fatal error: ffmpeg/avcodec.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [qp_movie.o] Error 1
checking for avcodec_init() in -lavcodec... yes
checking for av_register_all() in -lavformat... yes
checking for quadrupel_init() in -lquadrupel... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/home/ror_dev/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p362/bin/ruby
    --with-ffmpeg-dir
    --without-ffmpeg-dir
    --with-ffmpeg-include
    --without-ffmpeg-include=${ffmpeg-dir}/include
    --with-ffmpeg-lib
    --without-ffmpeg-lib=${ffmpeg-dir}/lib
    --with-quadrupel-dir
    --without-quadrupel-dir
    --with-quadrupel-include
    --without-quadrupel-include=${quadrupel-dir}/include
    --with-quadrupel-lib
    --without-quadrupel-lib=${quadrupel-dir}/lib
    --with-avcodeclib
    --without-avcodeclib
    --with-avformatlib
    --without-avformatlib
    --with-quadrupellib
    --without-quadrupellib
 extconf failed: need quadrupel library
```

First attempt was to relocate avcodec to where installer is searching for it. No success. Next - correcting paths in quadrupel files to point it to where avcodec is located. No success.

What is this quadrupel thing and how to force it to work?

Or maybe there is some replacement for rmovie?

Comment: https://github.com/streamio/streamio-ffmpeg seems to be a better option, it is more actively developed. rmovie was developed in 2006 and it may not be compatible with the current version of ffmpeg

Comment: Thank you @d33pika! `streamio-ffmpeg` is what I needed! Post your comment as answer and I'll pick it as best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [github.com/streamio/streamio-ffmpeg](http://github.com/streamio/streamio-ffmpeg), it is more actively developed. `rmovie` was developed in 2006 and it may not be compatible with the current version of `ffmpeg`

Answer (score 0):

Do like this -

1) Keep the gem in a gemfile -

```
 gem "rmovie", "~> 0.5.1"
```

2) Run `bundle install`

If still get errors try:

```
sudo apt-get install ffmpeg libavcodec-extra-52
```

If package not found try:

```
sudo apt-get install ffmpeg libavcodec-extra-53
```

you can also try to install the libmp3lame0 package:

```
sudo apt-get install libmp3lame0
```

Comment: Did it. Got same error: Installing rmovie (0.5.1) with native extensions 
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

Comment: what OS are you using - Windows or Ubuntu?

Comment: well it seems that your ffmpeg package is missing. See my updated answer and try.

Comment: Thanks, but same error is still there. Also, ffmpeg is installed and working. The problem is in this quadrupel. Even when I corrected qudarupel files to point it to correct location of ffmpeg it still showing errors

Comment: ok fine..that check this link as it may help you a great deal - https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/rmovie/iGY4FndFuos